# ipython for python 2.6.1 uninstall needed?

Tags: python, ipython

I installed ipython for python 2.6.1 using easy_install. After realizing that I needed the 2.7 version to use matplotlib, I downloaded and installed the resources to use ipython with python 2.7 using sudo. Do I need to uninstall the "old" ipython? If yes, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you shouldn't have to, the ipython package data is stored in the site-packages directory for the python version you installed it for, the ipython executable file basically contains

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

""" 
    long comment about IPython.Shell that you 
    might want to read; omitted here for brevity 
"""
import IPython.Shell

IPython.Shell.start().mainloop()
```

It will run using the default python version, you can call the 2.7 version directly using: `/path/to/python2.7 /path/to/ipython` if your default version of python is 2.6